# .NET Core 3.1 MVC with Web API Routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Having previously worked in .NET Framework, I'm now getting started with .NET Core.

I am building an application that is both MVC and Web API, and some of my routing is not working.

Here is my controller code:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
        public ClientController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("get works");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok("test not working");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/client/input")]
        public ActionResult input(int id)
        {
            return Ok(string.Format("Your id: {0}", id));
        }
    }
```

And here is my startup.cs code:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection")));
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

- https://localhost:5001/api/client works
- https://localhost:5001/api/client/test 404 error
- https://localhost:5001/api/client/2 404 error
- https://localhost:5001/api/client?id=2 404 error

I have tried adding specific routes to my individual actions and that had no effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not gain anything making route attribute like this for the controller

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientController : ControllerBase
```

You can remove any  attribute routing  from the controller with [ApiController] together  or make it like this

```
   [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientController : ControllerBase
```

in this case you can use this variants

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get() //api/client/get
        //or
         [HttpGet("GetAll")]
        public ActionResult Get() //api/client/getall

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Test() //api/client/test
        {
            return Ok("test not working");
        }
```

and fix input

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("~/api/client/input/{id}")] //api/client/input/4
        public ActionResult input(int id)
```

but it is the same

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult input(int id)
```

Comment: If I remove the route on the controller it gives an error message: "Action 'ProductPOC.Controllers.API.ClientController.Get' does not have an attribute route. Action methods on controllers annotated with ApiControllerAttribute must be attribute routed." That suggests to me that I'd then have to add a route to every single endpoint within the controller which goes against trying to tie-in to some default routing.

Comment: @MarkSeymour You have to remove [ApiController] too as I asked you in the answer

Comment: @MarkSeymour Or better live apicontroller and add full routing [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]

Comment: @MarkSeymour I am sorry, I didn' realize that you are using 3.1. Check my updated answer pls.